# How to use DB [ transaction , comit, rollback ] in adonis js

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonis.js

I want to use try catch with DB transaction for if I get something error I want the database rollback all of my query in try function

Here is my try. I comment `const empImg` because I want to test. It's not rollback  `await emp.save();` after the query error unknown `empImg`

```
  const trx = await Database.beginTransaction()
  try {
      const user = await auth.getUser();
      const emp = new Employee();
      emp.fill(empData);
      emp.merge({ update_by: user.name  })
      await emp.save();
      // const empImg = new EmployeePhoto();
      empImg.name = user.name;
      await empImg.save();
      await trx.commit()
    } catch (error) {
      await trx.rollback()
      throw new InvalidAccessException();
    }
```

Of course I can just put

`emp.delete();` in catch but I've to check which query error and delete it.

How can I do something like this If something error I want to rollback my emp and empImg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send *trx* object to Lucid functions for working with transactions mechanism, e.g. `await emp.save(trx);`

```
  const trx = await Database.beginTransaction()

  try {
      const user = await auth.getUser();
      const emp = new Employee();
      emp.fill(empData);
      emp.merge({ update_by: user.name  })
      await emp.save(trx);
      // const empImg = new EmployeePhoto();
      empImg.name = user.name;
      await empImg.save(trx);
      await trx.commit()
    } catch (error) {
      await trx.rollback()
      throw new InvalidAccessException();
    }
```

Transactions in [AdonisJS Docs](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/lucid#_transactions)